# Workaround for running php on a static page?

Tags: php, web, github-pages

I have a 'contact me' hosted on a git page that runs a very simple php script (name, email, anti-spam check, and message).

Now I understand that gitpages are static, and do not run any server side code, but I was wondering if there is a work around for this - say, running the php on an external php web service provider? Or using a built in webserver? Or embedding google forms?

I'd appreciate any help, or if you can point me in the right direction with my options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF GitHub allows it, use a off-site page to handle the script OR just use C-forms: https://form.c-sol.no

GitHub page:

```
<form action="http://your-site.tld/formsubmit.php" method="post">
FORM CONTENT
</form>
```

formsubmit.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$Name = html_specialchars($_POST['Name']);

//Your sendmail script
?>
```

Of course make sure that it is allowed by GitHub :)

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about GitHub pages: it would be a serious security issue if GitHub were to let its users run PHP scripts uploaded by them. The GitHub page is meant for showcasing and explanation, rather than running scripts. It's therefore rather fishy that you need to run a script every time someone visits your page.

As for embedding, you should see if GitHub allows this, I have not set up a GitHub page myself but I would be surprised if they'd let you embed external pages.